# Make: Target-specific variable assignment in function

Tags: makefile

Is it possible do the following in one `$(call ...)` inside a prerequisite list?

1. Assign an argument to a (private/non-inheriting) variable.
2. Add the argument to the target list.

That is, the following should assign the string `value` to the variable `$(var)`, while adding `value` as a prerequisite for the target `foo`.

```
foo: $(call assign-value-to-var,value)
    # Do stuff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, why not?

```
assign-value-to-var=$(eval foo: private var:=$1)$1

foo: $(call assign-value-to-var,value)
    # Do stuff
```

Comment: I actually didn't think of using an eval. :P